# Programmatically Setting Up File Filter for JFileChooser

Tags: java, arrays, jfilechooser, filefilter

I'm currently trying to add File Filter through the use of arrays (1D for description and 2D for the extension) as follows:

```
void findFile(){
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose file to upload");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

    ft = new FileType(this.chooser);
... //rest of code
}
```

FileType.java

```
package function;

import java.io.FileFilter;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileType {

    private String[] desc = {
        "Word Document (.doc, .docx)", "Excel Document (.xlsx, .xls)"
    };

    private String[][] ext = {
            {"doc", "docx"}, {"xlsx", "xls"}    
    };

    public int counts = desc.length;

    FileNameExtensionFilter fe;
    JFileChooser session;

    public FileType(JFileChooser session){
        this.session = session;

        generateCode();
    }

    void generateCode(){
        for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++){
            for(String pass : ext[i]){
                System.out.println(pass);
                generateFileType(desc[i], pass);    
            }
        }
    }

    public void generateFileType(String a, String...b){

        for(String x : b){
            fe = new FileNameExtensionFilter(a, x);
        }

        session.addChoosableFileFilter(fe);
    }

    /*public JFileChooser generateFilter(JFileChooser a){
        generateCode();
        for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++){
            a.addChoosableFileFilter(fe);
        }

        return a;
    }*/

}
```

Everything (almost) work, but I couldn't figure out how to merge the extensions into one description (i.e. it repeats the description, but with different extension filter).
[image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CykNk.png)

Did use varargs though, but I can't seem to find a way to pass multiple value at once inside `for` loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, what a stupid of me.
This was the answer:

```
void generateCode(){
    for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++){
        generateFileType(desc[i], ext[i]);  

    }
}

public void generateFileType(String a, String...b){
        fe = new FileNameExtensionFilter(a, b);


    session.addChoosableFileFilter(fe);
}
```

What I did last time is to iterate over the extension arrays, which made the program passes the value one-by-one.